# Spark: read multiple files and ignore the missing ones

Tags: apache-spark

I have an `Array[String]` that contains paths to some files.
The array is automatically generated so there is no guarantee that the files exist.

I would like to read all these paths, load the existing ones into an RDD, and ignore the non-existing ones.

I have tried to do the following:

```
import scala.util.Try

val arrayOfFilePaths: Array[String] = ["path1", "path2", "path3", "path4"]
val allRecords = sc.union(arrayOfFilePaths.map(p => Try(sc.textFile(p))).filter(_.isSuccess).map(_.get))
```

But it looks like it didn't succeed to avoid the non-existing files, I am getting the following error when I try `allRecords.collect()`:

```
Input path does not exist: file:/path/to/unexistingFile
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:285)
```

Any hint about what is wrong here?

Comment: the reason this filtering didn't work is spark's laziness: `sc.textFile(p)` is lazy - it returns an RDD without actually reading the file (yet), so `Try(sc.textFile(p))` returns a `Success` object regardless of file existence, and nothing gets filtered out. Then, when you call `collect` - that's when the reading actually happens, and it's too late for the filter to catch the failures. Your answer is indeed the right way to go.

Comment: Great explanation @TzachZohar, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I have figured out a solution.

I have filtered the array before loading the files.

```
import java.nio.file.{Paths, Files}

val filteredPaths = arrayOfFilePaths.filter(p => Files.exists(Paths.get(p))).mkString(",")
```

Then I can load these files

```
val allRecords = sc.textFile(filteredPaths)
```